# Jquery treeview

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/ for my application. Can I expand the nodes only on clicking the '+" icon. currenty, even when I click the text which comes after the '+' symbol the tree expands.

Answer (score 1):

open jquery.treeview.js

find 
`applyClasses: 
function(settings, toggler) {
            // TODO use event delegation
            this.filter(":has(>ul):not(:has(>a))").find(">span").unbind("click.treeview").bind("click.treeview", function(event) {
                // don't handle click events on children, eg. checkboxes
                if (this == event.target) 
                               toggler.apply($(this).next());
            }).add($("a", this)).hoverClass();`

and  comment `toggler.apply($(this).next());`

Comment: yes, but is there a way that doesn't involve actually digging into the library code?